# I can't push the loginViewcontroller with navigationController on self.window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I have point a `pageViewController` as the `rootViewController`,and then I wanna display a login view above the `pageViewController` if not sign in.

```
NLLoginViewController *loginVC = [[NLLoginViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
[self.window addSubview:navigation.view];
```

Comment: what exactly is not working and where do you get an error?

Comment: you are use a diffrent storyboard or not ?

Comment: Kayle Best see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following thing

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
NLLoginViewController *loginVC = [[NLLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NLLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
PageViewController *pageVC = [[PageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PageViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigation
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"is_SignedIn"]))
  navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:logindVC];
else
   navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:pageVC];
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
```

After that In login view controller, you have to set

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"is_SignedIn"];
```

Answer (score 0):

plz try this

```
UIStoryboard *   storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStorybordname" bundle:nil];

  NLLoginViewController *loginvc= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourviewControllerid"];

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginvc];
            self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```